# Sencha touch: push component more then one time not work

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a list with handler on list item disclose, when the user click on an item
I'm pushing a form view with the next code:

```
list.up('navigationview').push({
xtype: 'xEditAddFormPanel',
title: 'Edit task',
data: record.getData()
});
```

In the first click it's working and the navigation display the `xEditAddFormPanel`..

But then, after  click on the back button (and return to the list screen) and then press again on list item (what triggers the above code again) - now nothing happens.

How do I display the form screen again?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the reason was that the listener(s) is(are) lost the second time that you push a view into the navigator. Why? Because every time that you push a view into the Navigator the old view is destroyed, taking with it all listeners to the grave...

To get around this problem I binded the events manually whenever I create a new view that I wanted pushed:

```
onXButtonTap: function () {
    var view = Ext.create('MyApp.view.XEntryView');
    //Bind the events you need manually every time you push.
    view.on('myEvent', this.onSubmitNewX);
    this.getXMainView().push(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often in Sencha, you have to manually destroy components. You may need to do something like this:

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('YourApp.view.EditAddFormPanel', {
    title: 'Edit task',
    data: record.getData()
});

formPanel.onAfter('erased', function(){
    this.destroy();
}, this);

list.up('navigationview').push(formPanel);
```

Comment: When I destroy and then try to create and re-add I get the following error when I use the push function "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'detach' of null", what do you think?

Comment: Do you have `var formPanel = ...` or just `formPanel = ...` like I originally put above (now updated)? If the latter, try with `var` so it is scoped properly.